# Selenium Python - Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python, selenium

i am getting an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\x\index.py", line z, in <module>
    basket = item.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath')

(...)

selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

my code:

```
driver.get(urlx)
while not ac == "a":
    driver.refresh()
    list_items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("x")
    for item in list_items:
        basket = item.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath')
        xyz = wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 'xpath')))
        driver.get(xyz.get_attribute("href"))
        # (...)
        driver.get(urlx)
```

how should the code be error free?

Comment: Hi Erensi, I don't think your approach can be saved. In the loop, you navigate to a new page - that means everything else you collected previously (e.g. `list_items` and `basket`) are now stale. You can avoid stale elements by always referencing `driver` instead of your collections and there's potential around using the url as the iterator for the loop - but in order to help, you'll first need to please update your question with what you're actually trying to achieve :-)

Comment: @RichEdwards hello, how can I do this ("You can avoid stale elements by always referencing driver instead of your collections")? What I really want to do is to return to the previous page(urlx) if it cannot find a certain element on the page(xyz.get_attribute("href")) and repeat this process forever.

Comment: Can you provide the site and further details on what you're doing with the real identifiers so i can run some code to ensure it works without guessing?  -  To explain my previous comment, `driver.find_elements...` won't return stale element - it will always go to driver to get  "fresh" object after the page changes. Doing this: `item.find_element...` causes stale elements because **after the page changes** because your iterator: `item` is "out of date" (stale)

Comment: @RichEdwards I've shown the whole code on this topic ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66536954/getting-error-message-stale-element-reference-element-is-not-attached-to-the ). What I want to do is to find the products that are in stock on Amazon wishlist and go to the first product they find according to the price I have determined, and if there is no delivery to the country I am in, return to the wishlist and have it checked again.