# Getting Error: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

after going to a page and returning back to the previous page with driver.get(), I get this error while finding an element from that page:

```
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\x\index4.py", line y, in <module>
    basket = item.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath')
   
  (...)

selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

my code:

```
list_url = "URL"
driver.get(list_url)

staleElement = True
while staleElement:
    staleElement = False
    driver.refresh()
    list_items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("classname1")
    for item in list_items:
        basket = False
        try:
            basket = item.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath')
        except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException as e:
            basket = item.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath')

        if basket[0] and "text1" in basket[0].text:
            price = item.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath1')[0].text

            item_link = item.find_element_by_class_name("classname2").get_attribute("href")

            if int(price) < 101:
                driver.get(item_link)
                if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath2')) > 0:
                    driver.get(list_url)
                    staleElement = True
                else:
                    driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath3').click()
```

Comment: can you refresh the page without any negative consequences?  If so, maybe driver.refresh() after you have gone back to the page would help in getting the element out of stale state.  Not elegant and there are probably better solutions out there

Comment: Use a more index based xpath instead. It stops staleelement exceptions resulting from trying to go to a page and back.

Comment: Another way would be getting all the href values and then looping driver.get() with them outside the other loop.

Comment: usually this kind of problem is when you use `click()` or `get()` which loads new page and it remove previous page from memery and Selenium can't access elements on previous page - and it needs to split code in two parts: first part get all values from page (as strings, not references to objects on page), second part runs loop which use `click()` and `get()`

Comment: probably means that the elements in the list are still updating.  (find_elements won't wait)  You can either add a sleep or functionize the method there (finding list, iterating...), recall-ing if a Stale Element Exception is caught.   (include a sanity count check)

Comment: first you have to get all `"href"` (as strings) and later you can run code which load pages and go back (but if you already have all `"href"` then you don't even go back)

Comment: @ArundeepChohan "Use a more index based xpath instead. It stops staleelement exceptions resulting from trying to go to a page and back." I changed everything with xpath but it didn't work.

Comment: @pcalkins I added sleep(4) but nothing changed.

Comment: @furas How can I do what you wrote, can you write the code as it should be?

Comment: you have to create two `for`-loops. In current `for`-loop you have to append `item_link` to list (instead of `driver.get(item_link)`), And in second `for`-loop you should use `driver.get(item_link)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium doesn't gives real objects but only reference to objects in browser's memory and when you load new url (`driver.get(...)` or `click()`) then it loads new data to browser's memory and references to objects on previous page are outadted. They are outdated even if you load the previous page again (because objects may be in different place in browser's memory.

You have to use two `for`-loops.

If first `for`-loop you have to get all `"href"` (`item_link`) and append to some list (instead of `driver.get(item_link)`). And when you will have all `"href"` then in second `for`-loop you may use `driver.get(item_link)`.

I can't test it but it could be something like this:

```
list_url = "URL"

staleElement = True

while staleElement:
    staleElement = False

    driver.get(list_url)  # load page instead of refreshing because in next loop it may have different page in memory
    #driver.refresh()

    list_items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("classname1")

    # first for-loop: get all `hrefs` (as strings)
    
    all_hrefs = []  # list for all strings with `"href"`
    
    for item in list_items:
        basket = False
        try:
            basket = item.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath')
        except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException as e:
            basket = item.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath')

        if basket[0] and "text1" in basket[0].text:
            price = item.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath1')[0].text

            item_link = item.find_element_by_class_name("classname2").get_attribute("href")

            if int(price) < 101:
                all_href.append(item_link)  # add string `"href"` to list

    # second for-loop: use all `hrefs`

    for item_link in all_hrefs:
        driver.get(item_link)
        if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath2')) > 0:
            staleElement = True
            #driver.get(list_url)  # there is no need to go back to previous page
        #else:
        #    driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath3').click()  # there is no need to go back to previous page
```

Comment: thank you very much, I had to delete array because it was adding the same link to array dozens of times. The problem was solved when I removed the 2nd for as well and went directly to item_link.

Comment: if you get the same link dozens of times then it seems you need better `xpath` to get only one link - maybe you need `find_element_...` without `s` in word `element` to get only first element.